# Delete Row from Pandas DataFrame based on cell value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can i delete a row in a Pandas Dataframe, based on a cell value without giving a specific column name?

For example:

I have this DataFrame and i want to delete all rows where a cell contains the value 'd'.

```
   A B C D
1  1 2 d 5
2  1 3 4 0
3  d 2 1 2
4  3 2 1 7
```

So I end up with the DataFrame

```
  A B C D
2 1 3 4 0
4 3 2 1 7
```

Is there a way to achive this? My google skills only found solutions where a specific column name is required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do it this way:

```
df = df[~df.select_dtypes(['object']).eq('d').any(1)]
```

Result:

```
In [23]: df
Out[23]:
   A  B  C  D
2  1  3  4  0
4  3  2  1  7
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way you could do it to use `astype`, `ne` and `all`:

```
df[df.astype(str).ne('d').all(axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  D
2  1  3  4  0
4  3  2  1  7
```

Another way:

```
df.where(df.values != 'd').dropna()
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  D
2  1  3  4  0
4  3  2  1  7
```